# Spring security cross origin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I develop a REST API. Everything is working good, except the security (login, get logged user, etc ...)
When I log the user and then try to get it by **/getWhoAmI** endpoint, I can't get it (it returns *HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND* because there is no *authentication*). In **Postman** it is working great!

I do the following scenario: login user and then get it by /getWhoAmI. In postman, it works and returns the logged user but in my javascript application, it returns HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.

Also, I tried to debug it and in **getWhoAmI**, authentication is **null** (**only when I call it in JavaScript**, in postman it contains the authenticated user)

This is the **/getWhoAmI** endpoint

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/getWhoAmI")
public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getWhoAmI(Authentication authentication) {

    // if there is no authenticated user
    if(authentication == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    String loggedUsername = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    UserModel loggedUser = userRepo.findByUsername(loggedUsername);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(loggedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is my **SecurityConfig**:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailService;
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))) // return HttpStatus.OK after successfull logout
        .and().csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

**Login** endpoint:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/login")
public ResponseEntity<UserModel> login(
        @RequestParam(value = "username") String username, 
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {

    UserModel user = userRepo.findUserByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);

    if(user != null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if(userDetails != null) {
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            System.out.println(authentication);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

My front-end JavaScript:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: SERVER_URL + "/getWhoAmI",
    complete: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get it"? What is returned/thrown?

Comment: @StanOstrovskii it returns HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, because authentication is null. In other words - there is no authenticated user

Comment: Do those `.permitAll()` allow any request, including unauthenticated ones, to any URL and endpoint? Perhaps `.authenticated()` is needed for those that are to be protected by the login

Comment: @gears I added my login endpoint - check it.
I do the following scenario: login user and then get it by /getWhoAmI. In postman, it works and returns the logged user but in my javascript application it returns HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

Comment: @KaloyanVelichkov I was commenting on the use of `.permitAll()` in `SecurityConfig.configure(HttpSecurity)`. It looks like nothing requires the user to be authenticated. Also...how is it working in Postman - do you pass some session identifier like JSESSIONID cookie?

Comment: @gears why do I need .authenticated() in SecurityConfig? A stupid question, but where I have to add it? And yes, there is a JSESSIONID cookie by default in postman, I just saw it. Can't I use something like this cookie in my app too?

Comment: @KaloyanVelichkov The question mentions "cross origin"...For the browser to pass cookies in cross-site requests, the [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag has to be set to `true`. For example, via `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` for JQuery's `ajax` function, axios has similar `withCredentials` flag.

Comment: @gears I can't believe IT WORKS!!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KaloyanVelichkov Great! I'll add it as an answer - it may help others. Regarding `.permitAll()` - I'd suggest without signing in first you test accessing endpoints that are supposed to be protected by the login. In case access is granted to unauthenticated users/requests, you may have to look into replacing those `.permitAll()` with `.authenticated()` and having `.permitAll()` only for the endpoints related to authentication, like login and logout, and other endpoints that don't require authentication.

Comment: @gears I use annotation "@Secured" for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exchanged comments:

Because the calls from the front-end were cross-origin requests (CORS), the `ajax` call wasn't sending the session identifier cookie (JSESSIONID).

The [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag has to be set to `true` for cross-site requests to include credentials such as cookies and authorization headers.

For JQuery's `ajax` function that can be accomplished with `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`. axios has similar `withCredentials` flag.